# FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key) while building docker image in Github Actions

Tags: next.js, github-actions, google-cloud-run

I am trying to create a CI/CD process using GitHub Actions. The process includes testing, building the docker image and uploading it to Google Cloud Run.

Everything works fine when running the project locally, because locally I have access to the **.env** file. But this file is not been pushed to github repository.

The issue happens when the firebase is initialized, because all the values are inside the **.env** file

The error showed in the workflow logs is below:

```
#15 1.258 info  - Linting and checking validity of types...
#15 8.148 info  - Creating an optimized production build...
#15 19.76 info  - Compiled successfully
#15 19.76 info  - Collecting page data...
#15 20.33 FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
#15 20.33     at createErrorInternal (file:///app/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-3246d34e.js:467:40)
#15 20.33     at _assert (file:///app/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-3246d34e.js:471:15)
#15 20.33     at file:///app/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-3246d34e.js:6075:13
#15 20.33     at Component.instanceFactory (file:///app/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-3246d34e.js:6092:11)
#15 20.33     at Provider.getOrInitializeService (file:///app/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:290:39)
#15 20.33     at Provider.initialize (file:///app/node_modules/@firebase/component/dist/esm/index.esm2017.js:234:31)
#15 20.33     at initializeAuth (file:///app/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-3246d34e.js:585:27)
#15 20.33     at getAuth (file:///app/node_modules/@firebase/auth/dist/node-esm/index-3246d34e.js:6141:18)
#15 20.33     at /app/.next/server/chunks/933.js:121:68 ***
#15 20.33   code: 'auth/invalid-api-key',
#15 20.33   customData: *** appName: '[DEFAULT]' ***
#15 20.33 ***
```

I inserted the environment variable in the files:

- GitHub: Settings -> Security -> Secrets -> Actions
- Cloud Run: Environment variables
- next.config

  const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  output: 'standalone',
  env: {
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
  }
  }

  module.exports = nextConfig

Below is the workflow. I placed the environment variables for the building process and the push to cloud run process.

```
name: CI and CD

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches: [main, develop]

env:
  REGISTRY: gcr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_NAME }}/${{ secrets.CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE }}
  REGION: us-central1

jobs:
  test-code:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js 16.x
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: 16.x
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run test
  
  build-image:
    needs: test-code
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    outputs:
      tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
    concurrency: build-image-process
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Workaround: https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/issues/461
      - name: Setup Docker buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@79abd3f86f79a9d68a23c75a09a9a85889262adf
      
      # Login against a Docker registry except on PR
      # https://github.com/docker/login-action
      - name: Log into registry ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
        if: github.event_name != 'pull_request'
        uses: docker/login-action@28218f9b04b4f3f62068d7b6ce6ca5b26e35336c
        with:
          registry: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
          username: _json_key
          password: ${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}

      # Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
      # https://github.com/docker/metadata-action
      - name: Extract Docker metadata
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/${{ env.IMAGE_NAME }}
      
      # Build and push Docker image with Buildx (don't push on PR)
      # https://github.com/docker/build-push-action
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        id: build-and-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ac9327eae2b366085ac7f6a2d02df8aa8ead720a
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile.prod
          secrets: |
            "NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}"
            "NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}"
            "NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}"
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
          cache-from: type=gha
          cache-to: type=gha,mode=max
        
      - name: Outputs tags
        run: echo "${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}"

  deploy-image:
    needs: build-image
    if: github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:

      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
      - id: 'auth'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v0'
        with:
          credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GCP_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'
      
      - name: Build Image Outputs Tags
        run: echo "${{ needs.build-image.outputs.tags }}"
    
      - name: 'Deploy to Cloud Run'
        uses: 'google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0'
        with:
          service: ${{ secrets.CLOUD_RUN_SERVICE }}
          image: "${{ needs.build-image.outputs.tags }}"
          region: ${{ env.REGION }}
          env_vars: 
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}
```

I appreciate any help to make the whole process to work smoothly.

Comment: Did you find the issue, @Aliton Oliveira? I'm experiencing exactly the same issue. If I build the docker image locally, it works as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not found a definitive solution yet. But, I placed the environment variables inside the Dockerfile.

Comment: Yeah, I had to do the same. It seems that they are necessary for the build step.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The solution is to use `build-args` instead of `secrets` in the build step.

1. In your `Dockerfile` add the following. That will take the buld args and set them as env variables in the build context

```
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY

ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=$NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=$NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY=$NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PUBLIC_API_KEY
```

2. Change your build step to

```
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        id: build-and-push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ac9327eae2b366085ac7f6a2d02df8aa8ead720a
        if: ${{ github.event_name != 'pull_request' }}
        with:
          context: .
          file: ./Dockerfile.prod
          # The difference is here!
          build-args: |
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY }}
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN }}
            NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=${{ secrets.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID }}
```